# Running an EventMachine Worker on Heroku + Sinatra + Twitter Streaming API?

Tags: heroku, sinatra, eventmachine

I'm trying to get my head around the asynchronous pattern involved in running eventmachine on Heroku with Sinatra. In a nutshell, what I'm trying to achieve is this: using **em-http** create a http request to the twitter streaming api, on the *stream* callback, parse and push the tweet to clients using websockets. So far, so good. The problem arises when the same application also needs to serve webpages. In my config.ru I have, among other Bundler stuff,

```
require 'app'
run TwitterApp
```

Then in my app file, the EM block:

```
EM.run{
 class TwitterApp < Sinatra::Base {
       get '/' do
        haml :index
       end
 }
 http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url, options).get :head=>{'Authorization' => [USERNAME, PASSWORD]}
 http.stream do |chunk|
    #parse tweet, push using websockets
  end
}
```

Now, what seems to be happening is that **run TwitterApp** never gets reached because EventMachine uses the Reactor pattern and never returns.

Alternately, if I try to do a

```
App.run!
```

within the EM.run block, everything runs fine locally and running using **ruby app.rb**, but using *rackup* it seems to run the server twice (once with thin and the other with WEBrick) and on Heroku it crashes with

```
Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port other than $PORT
Stopping process with SIGKILL
```

Am I missing something very trivial here?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

For this, you could just run async_sinatra -- https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra -- and use its asynchronous handlers rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

I run the reactor in it's own thread so that it doesn't block the main process:

```
  if not EM.reactor_running?
    Thread.new {
      EM.run {
        logger.info "Starting EventMachine Reactor"
        EM.error_handler{ |e|
          logger.error "Error raised during event loop: #{e.message}"
          logger.error e.backtrace unless e.backtrace.nil?
        }
      }
    }
  else
    logger.info "Reactor already started"
  end
```

I then run things via

```
 EM.next_tick { do_background_stuff }
```

I am still waiting to find out you need to have a Worker Dyno to use this pattern.

Comment: > I am still waiting to find out you need to have a Worker Dyno to use this pattern. 

Did you find out?

Answer (score 1):

I am not so familiar with Eventmachine, but as far as I understand it, Websockets are not yet supported on Heroku. Projects like travis-ci get around that by using a service like Pusher to serve their Websockets.

The R11 (bad bind) error on Heroku means, that you have to make sure that your web worker binds to the port that it gets from Heroku (`ENV["PORT"]`). This makes sure the HTTP routing is supported I guess.

I hope this is helpful in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate your app into multiple server instances. App 1 serves web pages and App 2 runs the event-machine server (both are connected to the same db). You can use [Pusher](http://pusher.com) to glue it all together with web sockets.

Could you paste a gist of the full Sinatra app?